# Wearing teffilin without tallis

Tags: halacha, tzitzis

Can one wear teffilin after davening to learn without wearing a tallis (or even tallis katan)?

Comment: Why would you expect that they are contingent? Wearing tzitzit if you are not wearing a 4 cornered garment is not required - https://www.yeshiva.co/ask/57908 (and an unmarried Ashkenazi male generally doesn't wear a tallit), but an adult male must put on tefillin each weekday. How do you think they are connected?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. There's no prohibition on wearing tefillin without tallis.

Comment: A source would improve your answer

Comment: I feel like the burden of proof is on the one who assumes it's prohibited.

Answer (score 0):

Not clear why you would think otherwise, but they are 2 separate Mitzvot that seemingly have no connection.

But, if you need proof, the first Halacha in Hilchot Tefilin answers this in the affirmative.

It says in [Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim 25:1](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.25.1?lang=he&with=Commentary&lang2=he) - דיני תפילין בפרטות

> **א.** אחר שלבש טלית מצוייץ יניח תפילין **שמעלין בקדש** והמניחים כיס התפילין והטלית לתוך כיס אחת צריכין ליזהר שלא יניחו כיס התפילין למעלה כדי שלא יפגע בהם תחלה **ויצטרך להניחם קודם הטלית** כדי שלא יעבור על המצות:‏

After putting on your Tallis you put on your Tefilin **because you start with the lower Kedusha and then work your way up**.

Note, however, that he doesn't say that you have to be wearing your Tallis in order to wear your Tefilin. QED.

He then says that if your Tallis is hiding behind your Tefillin bag, you have to put on your Tefillin first. QED.

Furthermore, the Remo (ibid) says:

**הגה**: מיהו אם תפילין מזומנים בידו ואין לו ציצית **אין צריך להמתין על הציצית** אלא מניח תפילין וכשמביאים טלית מעטפו [דברי עצמו]:‏

If your Tallis isn't immediately available, then you can put on your Tefilin first, and when your Tallis arrives, you put it on. QED.

We see the same in the next Halacha - ibid [25:2](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.25.2?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he) - that one opinion is to put on your Tallis-Katan if you're particular to wear one, and put on your Teffilin at home and go to shul and only put on your Tallis once you get to shul.

> **ב**. מי שהוא זהיר בטלית קטן ילבשנו **ויניח תפילין בביתו** וילך לבוש בציצית ומוכתר בתפילין לבית הכנסת ושם יתעטף בטלית גדול:‏
> **הגה**: והעולם נהגו להתעטף אף בטלית גדול קודם ולברך עליו ואחר כך מניח התפילין והולך לבית הכנסת.:‏

From here you clearly see that it's OK to wear Tefilin without Tallis or Tallis-Katan, even for an extended amount of time, like walking an hour to shul.

The Remo does note that the custom is to put on your Tallis and Teffilin and then go to shul.

---

BTW: The מעשה רב in (60) records that the Vilna Gaon was particular to learn after davening with his Tallis and Rashi-Tefilin. ‏